# How to block website from MAC in the verizon router firewall settings

Tags: wireless-networking, router, firewall

I've tried searching for how to configure my verizon router firewall to block certain websites but nothing seems to be working. [Picture of what I've done here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WSud.jpg)

I did an nslookup for youtube.com and put in a range. Added in a MAC address for my son's iPod and I can still get to youtube via the Safari browser and when after I close and re-open the youtube app.

Using the MAC address was my last attempt. I've tried by IP, by the name I have assigned his device. I've tried hostname, even just a single IP.

So why is the firewall filtering not working? I'm hoping someone on here has tried this same thing as a guy from work said he was able to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear you've blocked access to all IP addresses used for youtube.com. E.g., when I do an nslookup on my system, I see the following:

```
C:\>nslookup youtube.com
Server:  localhost
Address:  ::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    youtube.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4004:80d::200e
          216.58.217.142
```

Google likely has a lot of different IP addresses for YouTube for [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) and the address or addresses someone may get returned for a [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) query for youtube.com may vary on geographic location and even for a particular location the IP address returned may not remain constant, so I'm not sure your method can be relied upon for cases such as this where there isn't just one IP address or a narrow range of IP addresses that will remain constant.

There may be another alternative available to you to block access to YouTube on the router they provided. What model of router did Verizon provide you? Since the "Advanced Filtering" screen shot you posted looks similar to what I see on a MI424WR router from Verizon at a client's site, I'll presume the model you have offers a similar user interface. If so, rather than going to "Advanced Filtering" to block YouTube by IP address range, click on "Parental Control" at the top of the screen you see when you connect to the router's web interface. In "Step 1" add your son's iPod as the selected device. In "Step 2", limit access by "Block the following Websites and Embedded Keywords within a Website".  Put youtube.com in the "website" field. Give the rule a name and description, then click on "Apply".

Alternatively, you could try the approach suggested by [Wim Remes](http://domdingelom.blogspot.com/) at [Blocking YouTube with a WRT54G](http://www.mckeay.net/2008/11/26/blocking-youtube-with-a-wrt54g/):

> use OpenDNS as your DNS provider instead of your ISP’s DNS servers.
>   OpenDNS provides a FREE parental control filter (category based) AND
>   allows you to block specific pages, as Martin explained in his post.
>   *this is ‘my way’ as anybody who wants to tinker with the settings needs an account to do so. If you’re really paranoid. Block port 53
>   TCP/UDP outgoing on your internet router/firewall so you’re prodigy
>   son can’t use other DNS servers.

[OpenDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) is a "a company and service which extends the Domain Name System (DNS) by adding features such as phishing protection and optional content filtering to traditional recursive DNS services." You could configure your router to provide OpenDNS DNS server IP addresses to devices on your home network rather than the default Verizon DNS server IP addresses.

Comment: I got scared of the Parental Controls because as I was about to apply the settings a message said it might degrade performance. I'll give the OpenDNS stuff a shot and fall back on the Parental Controls. Thanks!

Comment: The parental control would put an additional burden on the router. But so does adding firewall rules to look at source and destination IP addresses. However, it is much easier for the router to block on IP addresses. Blocking by domain name may require it to look deeper into packets to check the domain name in any attempts to access websites. I would expect that the additional check for just one domain name would add so insignificant an overhead that it wouldn't be noticeable. If you added hundreds of such blocks, perhaps you would notice it then, but I doubt you will otherwise.

Comment: For the free version of OpenDNS it will block certain categories or you can add websites for EVERYONE. I'm going to go with a combo of OpenDNS for general filtering and the Parental Controls so that I can still view youtube but the kids cannot. Thanks again for helping!